# Binary Search Tree to Linked List conversion converts only half of the entries

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree:

```
                3
               / \
              1   6
                   \
                    17
                   /
                 15
                /  \ 
               13   15
              /
             6
              \
               12 
              /
             9
```

And my function that converts the BST to a linked list where root points to the root of the BST:

```
ListNodePtr convertBSTtoLinkedList(TreeNodePtr root)
{
    ListNodePtr list,head;
    list = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    list->key = root->key;
    if (root->right != NULL)
    {
        list->next = convertBSTtoLinkedList(root->right);
    }
    if (root->left != NULL)  
    {
        head = convertBSTtoLinkedList(root->left);
        head->next = list;
        return head;
    }
    return list;
}
```

I have manually gone over my function for hours now and can't see what I've done wrong. I have verified that I am inputting a correctly made BST. My function to print out the list where head points to the start of the linked list:

```
void printList(ListNodePtr head)
{
  while (head->next != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d ",(head->key));
    head = head->next;
  }
  printf("%d ",(head->key));
}
```

Although I doubt that this function is incorrect.

My intended output is:

```
BST
1 3 6 6 9 12 13 15 15 17 
Linked list
1 3 6 6 9 12 13 15 15 17
```

However what comes out is:

```
BST
1 3 6 6 9 12 13 15 15 17 
Linked list
1 3 6 6 17
```

Comment: You should step through with a debugger to see where the behaviour diverges from what you expected.

Comment: Any recommendations for choice of debugger?

Comment: Too bad I've used all my votes, this would have been one of the couple C questions that deserved an upvote instead of the usual down, close and delete votes.

Comment: What do you mean you've used all your votes? Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow I don't really understand how it fully works.

Comment: @TheShield everyone is limited to only 40 votes (up or down) each day (the day starts at UTC 00:00). I used mine mostly downvoting bad C questions. You've got >15 reputation, so you can upvote, but not yet downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the leftmost tree, you're cutting off all but the head of the left tree and pointing that to the current node.  You want to walk to the *end* of that tree and point the end to the current node.

```
if (root->left != NULL)  
{
    ListNodePtr tail;
    head = convertBSTtoLinkedList(root->left);
    tail = head;
    while (tail->next != NULL) {
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    tail->next = list;
    return head;
}
```

Also, a minor optimization on your print function:

```
void printList(ListNodePtr head)
{
  while (head != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d ",(head->key));
    head = head->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that almost makes C++'s iterator pairs seem sane.

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense, thank you so much I've been stuck on this forever.